# Dropdown de Bootstrap ocupa mas de lo que deberia en movil

Tags: javascript, java, html, bootstrap

Buenas noches.

He metido un dropdown de bootstrap en mi web, funciona todo bien a excepcion de que en movil hace algo raro y al desplegarse unicamente, ocupa mas de lo que deberia y genera una banda negra en el lado y desplaza toda la web.
Como puedo solucionar esto?
Hay alguna manera de hacer que ese contenido no modifique el layout de la web? Me valdria como workaround.
He probado ha usar la propiedad overflfow: hidden para tratar de solucionarlo pero no ha cambiado nada.

Estoy usando Bootstrap 5 y la web es esta: [www.mingographics.com](http://www.mingographics.com).

Adjunto captura del bug ycodigo del burguer menu en html y el css que le da estilo.

[image: Captura del movil]

HTML del Burguer Menu

```
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle burguerboton"  type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="iconify" data-icon="dashicons:menu-alt" data-inline="false"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="social.html">Social</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="politics.html">Politics</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="music.html">Music</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="portrait.html">Portrait</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="artistic.html">Artistic</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="film.html">Film</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="sport.html">Sport</a></li>
              <li><a  class="enlacenegro" href="covid19.html">Covid-19</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider burguerinsta"></li>
              <li class="burguerinsta"><a  class="enlacenegro" href="https://www.instagram.com/mingo_graphics/" target="_blank">@Mingo_Graphics</a></li>
              <li class="burguerinsta"><a  class="enlacenegro" href="https://www.instagram.com/mingo_entropy/" target="_blank">@Mingo_Entropy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

CSS del Burguer Menu

```
  padding: 1.5px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: rgb(20, 36, 44);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #a2a2a2;
  margin: 3.4px;
}

.burguerboton{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.enlacenegro {
  color: #313131;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: -12px;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.iconify{
  color: white;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  border:15px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 130%;
  top: 10px !important;
  left: -11px !important;
  right: auto !important;
  bottom: auto !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.btn{
margin-right: -11px;
}

.btn-check:focus + .btn, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}

hr:not([size]) {
    height: 3px;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: El de initial-scale? No lo habia visto, voy a probar si eso cambia algo

Comment: Era un transform de bootstrap y el initial-scale mal escrito lo que hacia esos cambios raros, todo solucionado gracias a mirar los errores en la consola.

Comment: A entonces si lo viste jeje

Answer (score 0):

Pregunta resuelta, tenia en la meta tag de viewport mal escrito el "initial-scale" y por eso se me cambiaba la vista, con esa modificacion he descubierto que se estaba haciendo un transform: translate de bootstrap que no se de donde salia. Haciendo override a eso con 0 en todos los valores esta solucionado.